# Java8 to sort a Map value within Map

Tags: java, sorting

I have a map in this format: `Map<String, Map<Integer, Long>>`
and content like

```
{BCD={321=2}, ABC={123=1}, DEF={798=3}, CDE={564=1, 456=1}, GHI={908=2}}`
```

Is it possible sort the `Long` value reverse, then `String` and `Integer`?

Comment: Map is an unordered structure

Comment: What do you mean by "sort the long value reverse"?

Comment: It's not yet clear, what you are up to: You provide a datastructure which should be sorted. First question: what should be sorted? Please provide an example of the expected output. What entries should be eventually in the sorted array/list? Maybe you code an object which contains the named contents of your map to get a better understanding on your problem.

Comment: can you please specify the excepted output in the Question?

Comment: Follow the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275195/sort-a-hashmap-inside-a-map-based-on-value

Answer (score 1):

No. 
You cannot sort contents of a `Map`.

Sorting is only possible on things, which retain a sorting, like `List`, `TreeMap` or `TreeSet`.

If you want the `Map` contents to be sorted, just implement a `Comparator` (e.g. `Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Map<Integer, Long>>>`) which is capable of returning an integer representing the order of two entries and feed all contents of your `Map` into a `List<Map.Entry<String, Map<Integer, Long>>>`, which can then be sorted.

```
   private static final Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Map<Integer, Long>>> COMPI = new Comparator<>() {
          @Override
          public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Map<Integer, Long>> obj1,
               Map.Entry<String, Map<Integer, Long>>(obj2)) {
                   ... return 0, if obj1 equal to obj2
                   ... return 1, if obj1 lower than obj2
                   ... return -1, if obj1 greater than obj2
          }

          public static List<Map.Entry<String, Map<Integer, Long>>> sortMyMap(Map<String, Map<Integer, Long>> myMap) {
                List<Map.Entry<String, Map<Integer, Long>>> l = new java.util.ArrayList<>(myMap.entrySet());
                Collections.sort(l, COMPI);
                return l;
           }
}
```

The most difficult part would be to implement the comparator correctly...

Comment: Or a `TreeMap` maybe?

Comment: Just as a note, there is the general interface `SortedMap` which sums up suchs maps, mainly consisting of `TreeMap`. Theres also `LinkedHashMap` which retains insertion order (but not general sorting).

Comment: Well: ... and many other datastructures like Arrays, LinkedLists and other things. But especially a `java.util.Map` is not sortable per se, but only by transforming it somehow...